# Update git repository to submodule

Tags: git, branch, git-submodules

quick question, can I use submodule as "cloned repos"?

E.g.:
Can I change the submodule branch, and in case, edit the code and do some work in it and commit them?

Example:

```
 > example-repo
   |- index.html
   |- submodule -> submodule-repo-1
   |  |- file1.html
   |- submodule -> submodule-repo-2
      |- file2.html
```

and do something like:

```
git clone https://.../example-repo.git
git submodule update
cd submodule-repo-1
git checkout -b test-branch
echo "idk" > file1.html
git commit -am "test commit"
git push
```

Comment: You can do that but the superproject will [note that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69031416/7976758) and on `git status` will report the submodule as modified.

Comment: @phd and it creates problem? my main question is if using submodules I can work on all the submodules repository, or if I have to clone the submodules repositories on other folder, update them there and then run `submodule update`

Comment: If the remembering the new commits in the superproject is what you need then no problem, you can work directly in the submodule directory. Just don't forget — you must push new commits in the submodule before pushing the superproject to avoid the remote repo for superproject reference non-existing commit in a submodule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can indeed do that.  Remember that—at least for now<sup>1</sup>—a submodule doesn't really "know" that it *is* a submodule, so once you `cd` into it and start running Git commands (`git checkout`, `git add`, and so on), you're just working in an ordinary Git repository.  What makes this Git repository *be* a submodule is that once you exit out of it back to the *superproject*, certain Git commands *in* that superproject will run:

```
(cd submodule && git checkout $hash)
```

for specific hash IDs, for instance.

As a result, after you have made changes in a submodule's working tree, it's a good idea to get them committed and then `git push`-ed elsewhere, lest the superproject do something crazy like run `git checkout`, or *really* crazy like remove the submodule entirely.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>There is ongoing work in Git to make submodules more aware that they *are* submodules, to help fix items like footnote 2.

<sup>2</sup>This is pretty dangerous, so we don't normally want it, but: what happens, for instance, if `path/to/X` in commit `a1234567` is the submodule, but `path/to/X` in commit `b789abc` is a plain file?  Git tries hard not to destroy the submodule (or its clone)—these days, the submodule repository proper gets moved to a `.git/modules/` directory within the superproject—but it can be necessary.

Comment: thank you so much, very clean explanation.. just as a note, testing this turns out to be important to add `--remote --merge` when running `git submodules update` otherwise it will checkout a "detached  head"... just for those how are reading this and wants to use the submodules as working directory

Comment: Right - the `git submodule update` is the classic `(cd $path && git checkout $hash)` case, but recursive checkout also does that. Note that detached HEAD mode is *normal* in submodules! The `--remote --merge` flags will keep your current branch, but will run `git merge` as needed as well, creating new commits, which may not be what you want.